# Error el construir el Gradle Android Studio 1.5.1 (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.)

Tags: java, android, gradle

Tengo el siguiente error al intentar construir mi aplicación,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Supongo que tiene que ver con las dependencias que agrego al proyecto pero no logro solucionarlo, 
este es mi Build.Gradle(app): 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jmhe.corebo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/guava-17.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.3-javadoc.jar')
        compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.3-sources.jar')
        compile files('libs/mobileservices-2.0.3.jar')
        // compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
        compile project(':facebook')
        compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    }
```

Antes me construía, lo último que agregue al proyecto fue la plantilla predeterminada MapsActivity, con el resto todo estaba igual.

Comment: Intenta comentando las dependencias

Comment: Hola ya acabo de asegurarme que el problema está al añadir la plantilla del mapa de Google, sin ello funciona perfectamente, pero sigo sin saber exactamente como corregirlo, o que es lo que genera el conflicto

Comment: Prueba también lo de limpiar el proyecto y volver a crearlo, muchos problemas de gradle los solvento así. O bien prueba con la versión preview de Android Studio 2.0 beta 2

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer se estan compilando 2 veces tus dependencias:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Esa linea compila todos los jar y despues mas abajo los compilas cada uno.

Checa esta [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle) en ingles.

Answer (score 0):

Trate de añadir `multiDexEnabled true` al build.gradle en defaultConfig.

```
 defaultConfig {
    //..
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Nota: en algunos casos esto no solo no lo soluciona si no que genera mas errores si este es su caso **deshacer los cambios**.

P.D: si lo anterior soluciona el error puede querer usar solo la parte de los servicios de google que le interese aqui un ejemplo para analytics. En vez de usar por ejemplo compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:x.x.x'` cuando podria usar compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:x.x.x'` por ejemplo si solo necesita el `analytics`, con esto disminuira el tamaño de su apk y quizas no tenga que usar el `multiDexEnabled`.

Puede mirar mi respuesta aqui para un casos similares: [Ejecución fallida al querer levantar mi aplicación en Android Studio 1.5.1 (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2329/ejecuci%C3%B3n-fallida-al-querer-levantar-mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-en-android-studio-1-5-1/2331#2331)