# Ejecución fallida al querer levantar mi aplicación en Android Studio 1.5.1 (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.)

Tags: android, json, http, gradle

Soy nuevo en Android y quiero levantar una aplicacion basada a conexiones a BD pero me sale este error y no se como solucionarlo.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

esto es lo que hice con el build.gradle(Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stroler.vidapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-20140107.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr166.jar')
}
```

Comment: esta es la primera aplicacion que lanzas o a podido lanzar otras antes, me refiero si esta es la unica que falla o todas

Comment: bienvenido quizas quieras leer este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puede intentar varias cosas:

---

**1**

---

Lo primero que puede tratar es hacer es limpiar su proyecto `Clean`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*La imagen esta es sacada de Google Image.*

---

**2** (si con lo anterior no soluciono el problema)

---

Trate de añadir `multiDexEnabled true` al build.gradle. aunque este lo he visto mas veces como
 `(Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' .)`

```
 defaultConfig {
    //..
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**Nota:** en algunos casos esto no solo no lo soluciona si no que genera mas errores si este es su caso **deshacer los cambios**.

---

**3**(quizas esta sea la ultima que provaria no porque no crea que funcione sino porque es la mas tediosa de probar)

---

Esta respuesta es algo experimental, pues ultimamente he visto en varios foros (`www reddit com`) gente que esta teniendo errores similares al suyo, he leido algunas conversaciones y unos opinan que es por una cosa y otros por otra, pero el unico que vi que encontrara una solucion diferente a las que conocia fue un usuario que hizo lo siguiente (quizas no sea una solucion para usted, o que funcionado para usted algunos no lo consideren una solucion al cambiar del version, pero eso se convertiria en debate).

Agregar las siguentes lineas en su fichero:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

.

Quedando asi:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stroler.vidapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-20140107.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr166.jar')
}
```

Si después de estos cambios no le funciona algunos optaron por instalar el JDK 7, si opta por instalarlo asegúrese de comprobar que versión esta usando cuando al momento de compilar si aplicación. (configurar el PATH y todo eso).

Quizás a algunos le funcione con algunos cambios y otros no porque lo que he visto es que no siempre les coincide la ver, la suya por ejemplo es la jdk1.8.0_66, y en otro usuarios esta era la jdk1.8.0_65 por ejemplo.

---

**4**

---

Causado por repeticiones en gradle. aunque este lo he visto mas veces como
 `(failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.)`

> compile fileTree(include: [‘*.jar’], dir: ‘libs’)
>
> compile files(‘libs/xxx.jar’)

Podría tratarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') <- borrando esta linea

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-20140107.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr166.jar')
}
```

o

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'<- borrando esta linea
    //compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')<- borrando esta linea
    //compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')<- borrando esta linea
    //compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')<- borrando esta linea
    //compile files('libs/json-20140107.jar')<- borrando esta linea
    //compile files('libs/jsr166.jar')<- borrando esta linea
}
```

---

P.D: por eso le deje un comentario de si había ejecutado alguna antes de esta o si en todas les falla, pero como no contesto le dejo esta respuesta.

Si usted cree que puede estar sobrepasando el `dex limit` (tener mas de 65K métodos), por ejemplo si usa `google-play-services` en su aplicación o esta depende de muchas bibliotecas diferentes etc. un buen primer intento seria el `numero 2`. En su aplicación no veo que use google-play-services, pero es nombrado por si puede ayudar a otro usuario algunas veces se incluye lo siguiente por ejemplo `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:x.x.x'` cuando podría usar `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:x.x.x` por ejemplo si solo necesita el analytics.

Answer (score 1):

El error: **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.** :

```
 Error:Execution failed for task
 ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
 > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
```

se puede evitar agregando dentro de tu `build.gradle` la opción :

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Realiza el cambio en tu `build.gradle` y sincroniza tu proyecto con el archivo `build.gradle`.

---

En cuanto al error:

```
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

ocurre regularmente por falta de memoria, justamente estoy trabajando en una PC que regularmente tenia este problema, la solución temporal era reiniciar `Android Studio` para que funcionara correctamente.

Podrias solucionar este problema agregando esta opción dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
dexOptions {
    ...
    ...
    javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
}
```

en mi caso tengo configurado un `HeapSize` de 3GB.

Como otra opción puedes incrementar tu `HeapSize` desde `Android Studio`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size (inglés)